# Change display text based upon value

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying Errors on my Html page using Angular JS. The problem is I am receiving only error codes from the HTML . What are the various ways in which i can change the error code to the the Error text i like

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat='item in errorsd'>
<td align="left" class="validationMsg">&nbsp;{{item.message}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

If my item.message has one . I would like to display Beginner ,if its 2 Intermediate like that and so on . Should i use `ng-if ?` should i use `ng-switch` or should i input some logic on the controller side .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should i use ng-if ?

`ng-switch` is more readable and hence a better option. Later when you look back at the code it will be intuitive to you and other developers about what this code does.

> should i input some logic on the controller side .

Why put a logic in controller-side if the framework already provides a solution for such use-case?

I would do it like:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat='item in errorsd'>
    <td ng-switch="item.message" align="left" class="validationMsg">
      <span ng-switch-when="1">Beginner</span>
      <span ng-switch-when="2">Intermediate</span>
      <!-- and so on.. -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rahul

Answer (score 2):

I say use a switch statement inside of your controller.
So depending on the value, the global message would change thus displaying the correct one when triggering the validation msg box to show.